# Is every automorphism of $(\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ induced by a permutation of primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, prime-numbers, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $\sigma : \Bbb{P} \simeq \Bbb{P}$ be a permutation of primes extended to $0$ and negative primes via $\sigma(0) = 0$ and $\sigma(-p) = -\sigma(p)$ and finally extended to all of $\Bbb{Z}$ multiplicatively.  Let $S_{\Bbb{P}}$ be the monoid of all such maps.  Fix an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and define an equivalence relation on $S_{\Bbb{P}}$ to be $\sigma \sim \tau \iff \sigma(x) = \tau(x) \pmod n, \ \forall x \in \Bbb{Z}$.  This equivalence relation is compatible with composition in $S_{\Bbb{P}}$ or namely $\sigma \sim \tau$ and $\sigma' \sim \tau' \implies [\sigma(\sigma')] = [\tau(\tau')]$.  Therefore $S_{\Bbb{P}} / \sim$ is a quotient group of $S_{\Bbb{P}}$.  Define $\sigma^* : (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times} \simeq (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ to be $\sigma^*(\overline{x}) = \overline{\sigma(x)}$.  We say that $\sigma$ induces $\sigma^*$.  Clearly $\sigma^*$ is an automorphism of $(\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ by the properties of $\sigma$.  Thus $\cdot^* : S_{\Bbb{P}}/\sim \to \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ is is a group homomorphism.  Is it surjective?

Comment: If we need to, take $\Bbb{P} = \{ p : p \nmid n\}$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This equivalence relation is compatible with composition in $S_{\Bbb{P}}$ or namely $\sigma \sim \tau$ and $\sigma' \sim \tau' \implies [\sigma(\sigma')] = [\tau(\tau')]$.

Unfortunately, the proposition above is false.

Here is an example. Let $\sigma, \sigma', \tau,\tau'$ be the identity map on all primes except on $\{3,5,7,13\}$, where they are defined by the following table.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
 &3 &5 &7 & 13\\\hline
\sigma &13 &7 &3 &5\\\hline
\tau &13 &3 &7 &5\\\hline
\sigma'&5 &3 &13 &7\\\hline
\tau' &13 &7 &5 &3\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Fix $n=4$. Then $\sigma \sim \tau$ and $\sigma' \sim \tau'$. However, $$\sigma(\sigma')(3) =\sigma(5)= 7,$$ $$\tau(\tau')(3)=\tau(13)=5.$$
Since $7\not\equiv5\pmod4$, $ [\sigma(\sigma')] \not= [\tau(\tau')]$.